# Render a Table the "wrong" way: transpose Columns and Rows?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to draw a table using the standard while(mysql_fetch_assoc) where the left most column is the header like this:

```
Name      | Peter Jacksson    | Steven Spielberg | Martin Scorsese |
Birthyear | 1961              | 1946             | 1942 |
Movie     | Lord of the Rings | Jurassic Park    | Cape Fear |
```

(Rats! SO doesn't support the table-tag).

Comment: You could create an array of strings and then add the specific column to the fitting array element while iterating above your results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do this by adding the elements to an array structure and then printing that structure:

```
$data = array('name' => array(), 'birth' => array(), 'movie' => array());
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc(...)) {
  $data['name'][] = $r['name'];
  ...
}

echo '<th>Name</th>';
foreach($data['name'] as $n) {
  printf('<td>%s</td>', htmlspecialchars($n));
}
...
```

Comment: Why the extra '[]' on the $data-variable on line 3 or is it just a typo?

Comment: It's not a typo. `$data['name']` itself is an array and I am adding elements to it. Read the manual on arrays if you still don't understand the syntax.