# Display PHP Data in 2 Columns

Tags: php

Here's my code:

```
echo "<table><tr>";
$count = 1; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
extract($row);
$data = $row['info'];
echo "<td>".$data."</td>"; 
if ($count++ % 2 == 0) {
echo "</tr><tr>";
} 
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

The above code works as:

```
=========
= 1 = 2 =
= 3 = 4 =
= 5 = 6 =
=========
```

But how do I display the info in this format?

```
=========
= 1 = 4 =
= 2 = 5 =
= 3 = 6 =
=========
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render a Table the "wrong" way: transpose Columns and Rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838162/render-a-table-the-wrong-way-transpose-columns-and-rows)

Comment: No. It's a different thing. I want to display half of the rows in the first column and the other half in the second column.

Comment: Create an array of all the results. Then split it up into two arrays, and output `$array1[$row]` and `$array2[$row]` on each row.

Comment: Thanks, but with the code above how would I do it? Isn't the third line which is while `($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {` already an array? If so, where would I insert `$array1[$row]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Sorting files in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823859/php-sorting-files-in-a-table)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to parse array to another form...

```
<?php
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$c = ceil(count($a)/2);
echo "<table>";
for($i=0; $i<$c;++$i){
    echo "<tr><td>{$a[$i]}</td><td>{$a[$i+$c]}</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Ofcourse you need to modify this code by adding db operations (like mysql_num_rows instead of count) but it works fine: [enter link description here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/rha-vu2)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, guys! I appreciate all your help, but this code works perfect for me. I just want to share it with others who may find this helpful. :)

```
$tmp=array(); 
$columns=2; 

$row=ceil(mysql_num_rows($result)/$columns);  
for ($x =1; $x <= $columns; $x++) 
  for ($y = 1; $y <= $row; $y++) 
     $tmp[$x][$y]=mysql_fetch_array($result); 

echo "<table align=center width=\"50%\">\n"; 
  for ($y =1; $y <= $row; $y++) { 
   echo "<tr>"; 
  for ($x = 1; $x <= $columns; $x++) 
    if (isset($tmp[$x][$y]['ID'])) 
        echo "<td>".$tmp[$x][$y]['info']." </a></td>"; 
    else 
        echo "<td></td>"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
} 
echo "</table>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

A brief PSA... the `mysql_` extension is depreciated and will eventually be removed. You need to start using `mysqli_` now.

You need to parse your data first. Once you've done that, generating the table is easy. This should work for all data sets

```
echo "<table>";
$count = 1;
$col1 = $col2 = array();
$rowcount = round(mysql_num_rows($result) / 2);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    if($count > $rowcount) $col2[] = $row['info'];
    else $col1[] = $row['info'];
    $count++;
}
$counter = 0; // Arrays start with 0
foreach($col1 as $row) { // $col1 will always be >= $col2
    $row2 = (isset($col2[$counter])) ? $col2[$counter] : "";
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row . "</td><td>" . $row2 . "</td></tr>"; 
    $counter++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but you can acheive this cleanly with 2 loops. Build up the left and right columns based on the the `$count` variable. Build the HTML all the way up, then echo it.

Edit: I didn't realize you were dividing the data in half and placing the first half on the left column of the table. I have changed the code below to do this.

```
<?php

$left = array();
$right = array();
$count = 1;

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if ($count <= $num_rows/2) {
        array_push($left, $row['info']);
    } else {
        array_push($right, $row['info']);
    }
    $count++;
}

$html = "<table>";

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $html .= "<tr><td>" 
        . htmlentities($left[$i]) 
        . "</td><td>"
        . htmlentities($right[$i])
        . "</td></tr>";
}

$html .= "</table>";

echo $html;

?>
```

Comment: I think this prints the table in the same order as the original.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some php magic that could shorten that code for a bit

```
<?php    
 $array = range(1, 20);

 $count = 2;
 $out = array_chunk($array, ceil(count($array)/$count));
 array_unshift($out, null);
 $out = call_user_func_array("array_map", $out);

?>
<table>
    <?php foreach ($out as $row) : ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach($row as $column) : ?>
                <td><?php echo( $column ); ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Also, i would recommend you switch your database-related code to PDO. Besides all those nice features, like auto-escaping, you can easily get an array of elements from your DB query, without all this `mysql_fetch_array` nonsense.